# HTML Button Not Working After Copy to Different Folder

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

so I have a html page that I created on my local computer. I copied that over to a shared drive that multiple people will have access to. When I copied the file however, for some reason the dropdown menu I created stopped functioning in IE11, but works in Chrome and Firefox. So I think it may be a browser issue. But, that doesn't explain why the same file copied to a different folder doesn't work the same. I even made sure to change all referenced links, since they were referencing html pages on the local computer. Any advice as to what could be happening?

dropdown menu "div":

```
<div class="dropdown">
 <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Select Toolset</button>
 <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
  <a href="#" onclick="filterALL()">All REG Tools</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="filter500()">A500 Tool(s)</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="filter3p()">A300+ Tools</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="filter300()">A300 Tools</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="filterXT()">XT+ Tools</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="filterPMON()">PMON Charts</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="filterSMON()">SMON Charts</a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Js for dropdown:

```
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
 document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

 var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
 var i;
 for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
  var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
  if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
    openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
   }
  }
 }
}
```

When I run it in IE11, it stops it and asks to bring up the debugger. When I do, I see that it is saying this: "Unable to get property 'toggle' of undefined or null reference".

Sorry in advance if this is just a misunderstanding of HTML. Definitely just learning.

Comment: IE may have decided to open the page in compatibility mode, defaulting to older IE behaviour that doesn't support `.classList` - the dev tools should show you which mode it is in. (By the way, there's no need to show the HTML and JS twice in your question if the "original" and "copied" are the same.)

Comment: @nnnnnn, Oh ok I see. And yes you were correct. Running from my local drive, IE uses Edge for the document mode, but from the copied drive, it switches it to IE7. As far as the double copy, I just wanted to make sure I didn't miss anything or maybe something in my code was wrong or something. Removed the "copy". Thanks